# "graph2vec" input data format

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, graph, word2vec, gensim

I would like to apply "graph2vec" code to a my own dataset. However I can not figure out how to properly format the input data nor understand the input data format of examples available on "github" page of the authors. A network in my dataset has integer nodes and binary label, so it is a dataframe with three columns. I appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction.

"graph2vec" on github:   https://github.com/MLDroid/graph2vec_tf

"graph2vec" on arxiv:   https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.05005.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In file `make_graph2vec_corpus.py` which is part of the source of `graph2vec` you can read

```
graphs = [nx.read_gexf(fname) for fname in fnames]
```

which means that the graph files are read through the `read_gexf` method of the `networkx` package. Indeed, as it stands and unless you change that code, the data must be in [GEXF format](https://gephi.org/gexf/format/).

GEXF files are coded in XML, they contain a main element called `gexf`, which  contains an element `graph`, which again contains three sub-elements: `attributes`, `nodes` and `edges`.

In our case, the `attributes` element has a single child:

```
<attribute id="0" title="Label" type="string" />
```

which means that you need an attribute number `0` for an attribute which contains a numeric property of the node (for example if your graphs are dependency trees of sentences then that property can be the index of the word in your embedding, or again its POS tag, or whatever). The `nodes` element contains one

```
  <node id="0" label="0">
    <attvalues>
      <attvalue for="0" value="3" />
    </attvalues>
  </node>
```

child for each node of the graph. In it, the `attvalue` sub-element contains the numeric property of the node. Finally, the `edges` element contains one child

```
  <edge id="0" source="0" target="1" />
```

for every edge of the graph: here we have the label of the edge as attribute `id`, the label of the source node as `source` and the label of the target node as `target`.

If you want to take a look at a sample GEXF file, they are located in the `data.tar.gz` archive inside the `graph2vec` package.

Besides the data of each individual graph (consisting of nodes with their numeric properties and edges), you also need to supply the classes of graphs in your training data. These are stored in a file with extension `.Labels` containing a single line for each graph:

```
0.gexf 6
```

where `0.gexf` is the name of the GEXF file containing the graph and `6` is its class.